Nuxt3 how to store user data correctly after logging in
I want to store user data after a person logs in, I also use middleware on the "/page" page that looks at whether the user is logged in, if so, he skips, but I have user data stored until the page is refreshed and if a person refreshes the page on ""/page" tc Nuxt3 will not have time to make a request for the user will say that he is not authorized and after a moment authorizes him again, is there any storage that allows you to do this, I would be grateful for the material to teach this.
trying use localStorage but nuxt3 didnt define user fast

I am not use to nuxt but seems like state management issue
Check this out Nuxt Store Not Keeping Logged in

sorry, but as it seemed to me this solution is not relevant, the author of the repository has not updated it for 2 years
